# Tesseract not respecting spacing between some characters

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using Tesseract to pull some text out of different screens. I am having issues with the following, where the spacing between characters is not being recognized as I'd hope:
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXiuX.png)

With no Tesseract configurations set, I get the following output:
`V firm_1.11 | IDtt11`
where I would hope for:
`V firm_1.11 | ID t t 1 1`

I have tried adjusting the `tosp_min_sane_kn_sp` as well as many `tosp_` parameters, but have not been able to seperate the t's and 1's. I have also tried applying an erosion and dilation before reading using opencv but have not seen improvements. What other configurations or image processing tricks could I try?